# How to design a Teacher-Parent database to cope with scale?

Tags: sql, node.js, database, database-design, nosql

We are trying to build a teacher and parent communication platform. We have around 500 schools, 300,000 students, 30,000 teachers and 500,000 parents on the platform for the first-year.

### Features overview:

1. A teacher from any school can send images,videos,text information to that school kids' parents.
2. We have to save attendance of each student of a class in a db
3. School can post events,announcements or

I'm thinking the below designs

```
Design 1

All students from all the schools are in one table , Max 300,000 rows
All teachers from all the schools are in one table,  Max 30,000 rows
All events,posts from all the schools are in one table., INCREMETNS BY 1500 every day.
All the schools attendance data in single table.. increments 300,000 per a day.


Design 2
    Separating tables at school level,
    school_1_students table contains only school_1 student details,
    school_2_students table contains only school_2 student details,
    So totally 300 schools * 5 tables = 1500 tables

Design 3
  Separating databases at school level,
  School_1_db contains all the tables of school1, 
so totally 300+ dbs.
```

Design 1 is easy and differentiate at row level, Only attendance is the table which actually adds 300,000 rows a day, should we separate only this table to school level or any suggestion?

Design 2 creates 1000+ tables in a single database and almost all the tables' schema is the same.

Design 3 gives good separation and can we dynamically work with different databases with nodejs and how to manage connections to multiple dbs?

The students and parents will increase year-by-year. So we have to think about future system survival. Should we go-with NOSQL or SQL?

What's the industry practice for this kind of system? Please suggest some changes or references.

Comment: If you have data in your table name then you do something wrong like `school1_students` - that is plain wrong. And there is no problem in storing even billions of records in a table. Just use proper indexes and design 1

Comment: You should absolutely stick with an RDBMS. MySQL, PostgreSQL, etc will be fine. This is very tabular data, so NoSQL is likely to be a mistake. From a data security perspective, some schools _may_ ask you to put their data in a separate db/tablespace or to guarantee some data isolation, so you might need to think about that.